# Building typescript with MsBuild to single file

Tags: typescript, msbuild

Is it possible to compile typescript in Visual Studio to single file (with MsBuild). I am using Visual Studio Community 2015, with typescript 1.8.9.

Setting `<TypeScriptOutFile>bundle.js</TypeScriptOutFile>` doesn' t work, cause I am using CommonJS modules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can not

From [Why not supported outFile parameter on CommonJS](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7252)

I quote from mhegazy:

"CommonJs expects files to exist at certain places, and changing their location breaks how they are loaded. moreover CommonJs/node modules have different scoping rules than script files, and concatenating them breaks that, so the only way to do this correctly is to wrap them in functions, and add a loader, which is pretty much AMD or system.js."

Then if you want to use one output file name use AMD..